# How to classify all the abelian groups with finite exponent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group, the exponent exp$A$ is the least natural number $n$ (if exists) such that $nA=0$ or $+\infty$. The question can be reduced to the case exp$A=p^n$ for a certain prime number $p$ easily. But then I have no ideal. I'm not very sure if such a group must be a direct sum of cyclic groups, just like the finitely generated case. In particular, I'm not very sure if a infinite **direct product** of $C_{p^n}$ is **direct sum** of cyclic groups.

Comment: Then why not try top prove a result that every such group is the product of cyclic groups?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I tried, but I failed.

Comment: @hagen, that cannot work because there are countable abelian groups of finite exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find in the first few pages of Irvin Kaplansky
's book *Infinite abelian groups* a proof of the statement that an abelian group of finite exponent is a direct sum of cyclic groups.