# Homomorphism between a group of exponent $m$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be an abelian group of exponent $m$, where $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there always a nontrivial group homomorphism between $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ ?

For example, if we have $G=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ the map $f(x)=x$ is one such homomorphism. If we have $G= \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, then $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y)\text{ ( mod }m)$ is another such map.

In the above examples, we have a precise description of $G$. What if we don't know what $G$ looks like? Can we construct a nontrivial homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Should the question be 'is there always a non-trivial group homomorphism'? Otherwise, unless I'm mistaken, we can just give any non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ to itself

Comment: There should always be one, because $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is an injective $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$-module (and the exponent of $G$ is precisely $m$).

Comment: There are several votes to close. I think the command "If yes, give some examples" is the most off-putting part of the question.

Comment: I don't know about injective $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ modules. Could you explain it in a simpler way ? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: Is $G$ finite? Is $G$ finitely generated?

Comment: @pjs36  That is odd.  A lot of math questions contain imperatives such as "prove that ...," "show that ...," etc.  It is quite weird that someone would pick this particular instance to feel offended.  I have created many questions with such phrases, yet my questions have never been voted to close (except when they are duplicates of other threads).

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, my comment was "lacking context" you might say. I was just trying to explain what I *assumed* were the motivations of those voting to close. I didn't really mind the question, I assume it has a nontrivial answer. But it still would have been better phrased as, "I can't prove it and I've looked for counterexamples, but I'm not really sure what they should look like" etc. etc. Just offering *something* besides the imperative. I just didn't want to leave a comment *this* long, but since I wound up doing so anyway...

Answer (score 1):

> **[The First Prüfer Theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_theorems)**  An abelian group of bounded exponent is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups.

If $G$ is an abelian group of exponent $m\in\mathbb{N}$, then $G$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups according to the theorem above, from which we may assume that
$$G\cong\bigoplus_{p}\,\bigoplus_{k=1}^{l(p)}\,\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\oplus \alpha(p,k)}\,,$$
where $p$ runs over the prime natural numbers dividing $m$, $l(p)$ is the highest exponent of $p$ that divides $m$, and $\alpha(p,k)$ is a cardinal number for each $k=1,2,\ldots,l(p)$.  Note that $\alpha\big(p,l(p)\big)>0$ for all primes $p$ dividing $m$ (or $G$ would be of a smaller exponent).   Let
$$H:=\left(\bigoplus_{p}\,\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{l(p)}\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\alpha\big(p,l(p)\big)-1}\right)\oplus\left(\bigoplus_{p}\,\bigoplus_{k=1}^{l(p)-1}\,\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\oplus \alpha(p,k)}\right)\,,$$
where we interpret $\alpha\big(p,l(p)\big)-1$ as $\alpha\big(p,l(p)\big)$ if $\alpha\big(p,l(p)\big)$ is an infinite cardinal number.
Then, 
$$G\cong  \left(\bigoplus_{p}\,\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{l(p)}\mathbb{Z}\right)\right)\oplus H\cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})\oplus H\,.$$ Hence, we have a nontrivial group homomorphism $$G\overset{\cong}{\rightarrow} (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})\oplus H\overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\,,$$ where $\pi$ is the canonical projection.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [the structure theorems for finite abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification), then it is easy because

> In the invariant factor decomposition, the largest factor has order equal to the exponent of $G$.

If you cannot use the structure theorems, see
[Chapter 2](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387405100-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-107321-p14004925) of the book [*The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97433), by Kurzweil and Stellmacher. It contains this elementary theorem, which does not depend on the structure theorem of finite abelian groups:

> If $G$ is a finite abelian group and $U$ is a cyclic subgroup of maximal order $m$ in $G$, then there $o(y)$ divides $m$ for all $y \in G$.

From this, it follows that $m=\exp G$ because $o(y) \mid m$ for all $y$ implies $\exp G \mid m$, and $U=\langle u \rangle$ implies $m=ord(u) \mid \exp G$.

The next theorem in that book is:

> If $G$ is a finite abelian group and $U$ is a cyclic subgroup of maximal order in $G$, then there exists a complement $V$ of
>   $U$ in $G$, that is, $G=UV$ and $U \cap V =1$. In particular, $G \cong U \times V$.

This gives you a surjective group homomorphism $G \to U \cong\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277205/if-oa-is-equal-to-exponent-of-finite-abelian-group-g-then-g-a-times-k

Comment: You are assuming $G$ to be finite? Because I don't see this assumption in the question.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Oops! If $G$ is finitely generated, then my answer applies to $tor\ G$, which is finite. Otherwise, I don't know anything about non-finitely generated abelain groups...

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, there are some pointers in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193556/how-to-classify-all-the-abelian-groups-with-finite-exponent.